# How to show user data in Text or TextField flutter

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, textfield

I want to show the data that the user has written into the TextField in the Container as a Text. While receiving data, I gave the Container a constant height and set maxLines: 10000 for the TextField, so as the user writes in without overflowing outside the Container, the text moves up inside the Container. Is there a structure where I can show output user data in this way? When i try to show output in same way, it doesn't show overflowed text, how i make it scrollable?

Here is user data receiving code:

```
 Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               horizontal: 4,
             ),
             child: Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 7 / 10,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 border: Border.all(
                   color: UserColorHelper.Blue,
                   width: 1,
                 ),
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
               ),
               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                 child: TextField(
                   decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                       hintText: "Note here..."),
                   style: TextStyle(color: UserColorHelper.Light),
                   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                   maxLines: 10000,
                   textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                   autofocus: false,
                   onEditingComplete: () {},
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
```

[Text_Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K97C0.png)

Answer (score 0):

use   TextEditingController

add

```
 controller: reasonController,
```

fix your code to :

```
  final reasonController = TextEditingController();


Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 4,
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 7 / 10,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: UserColorHelper.Blue,
            width: 1,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: TextField(
            controller: reasonController,
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                hintText: "Note here..."),
            style: TextStyle(color: UserColorHelper.Light),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            maxLines: 10000,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            autofocus: false,
            onEditingComplete: () {
              print(reasonController.text);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

get text from Controller

```
print(reasonController.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow property of textfield(), do something like this,

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

OR

```
overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
```

Comment: to think text in the image as a received data, it doesn't show overflowed text, how i make it scrollable? [overflowed text in container](https://i.ibb.co/xCHQdPJ/overflow.png)